# In a one to many relationship, is there a way to filter the parent objects via an attribute of the child?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a rails backend with the following relationships: a USER has many MOVES. a Move has many boxes. A Box has many items.

I have page that lists all of the boxes inside of a specific move and this page ALSO lists all of the items for that specific move. I have a search bar on this page that enables you to search for specific items. I am able to filter my items display, however, i cannot figure out how to filter my boxes BY the searching for the name of the items WITHIN them.

I have tried iterating over the array of Box objects, and then iterating over the key within each box that points to its array of items. I am able to get the filtered ITEMS, but I dont know how to translate that back to reflect the BOXES with those items.

For instance, in the console I tried:

```
    var filteredBoxes = boxes.map((box) => {
      return box.items.filter((i) => {
         return i.name.includes(this.state.searchTerm)
       })
     })
```

But it keeps returning items, not the boxes im trying to filter.

This is how the JSON looks when I fetch my boxes. I used a serializer to list the items as well:

```
{
id: 1,
name: "Bedding",
category: "Bedroom",
move_id: 1,
move: {
id: 1,
name: "Leaving for College",
date: "2019-08-12",
user_id: 1
},
items: [
{
id: 1,
name: "Comforter",
image: "https://www.shopmarriott.com/images/products/v2/lrg/Marriott-down-duvet-comforter-MAR-112_1_lrg.jpg",
box_id: 1
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Throw Pillows",
image: "https://media.kohlsimg.com/is/image/kohls/3427815?wid=500&hei=500&op_sharpen=1",
box_id: 1
}
]
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Random Blankets",
category: "Den",
move_id: 1,
move: {
id: 1,
name: "Leaving for College",
date: "2019-08-12",
user_id: 1
},
items: [
{
id: 3,
name: "Pillows",
image: "https://www.greatsleep.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-tbp-master-catalog/default/dw9ff5c1cf/product-images/pillows/nautica/down-alt-pillow-2-pack-na-91644/nautica-down-alternative-pillow-2-pack_91644-icon-2500x2500.jpg",
box_id: 2
},
{
id: 4,
name: "Stuffed Animals",
image: "https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0817201617082870M?resmode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1&wid=550&hei=550",
box_id: 2
}
]
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Cleaning Supplies",
category: "Kitchen",
move_id: 1,
move: {
id: 1,
name: "Leaving for College",
date: "2019-08-12",
user_id: 1
},
items: [
{
id: 5,
name: "Pillows",
image: "https://www.greatsleep.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-tbp-master-catalog/default/dw9ff5c1cf/product-images/pillows/nautica/down-alt-pillow-2-pack-na-91644/nautica-down-alternative-pillow-2-pack_91644-icon-2500x2500.jpg",
box_id: 3
},
{
id: 6,
name: "Stuffed Animals",
image: "https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0817201617082870M?resmode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1&wid=550&hei=550",
box_id: 3
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to iterate boxes, and so filter items. Based on these filtered items you may choose to return or not a box to the list.

```js
const data = [{
   id:1,
   name:"Bedding",
   category:"Bedroom",
   move_id:1,
   move:{
      id:1,
      name:"Leaving for College",
      date:"2019-08-12",
      user_id:1
   },
   items:[
      {
         id:1,
         name:"Comforter",
         image:"https://www.shopmarriott.com/images/products/v2/lrg/Marriott-down-duvet-comforter-MAR-112_1_lrg.jpg",
         box_id:1
      },
      {
         id:2,
         name:"Throw Pillows",
         image:"https://media.kohlsimg.com/is/image/kohls/3427815?wid=500&hei=500&op_sharpen=1",
         box_id:1
      }
   ]
},
{
   id:2,
   name:"Random Blankets",
   category:"Den",
   move_id:1,
   move:{
      id:1,
      name:"Leaving for College",
      date:"2019-08-12",
      user_id:1
   },
   items:[
      {
         id:3,
         name:"Pillows",
         image:"https://www.greatsleep.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-tbp-master-catalog/default/dw9ff5c1cf/product-images/pillows/nautica/down-alt-pillow-2-pack-na-91644/nautica-down-alternative-pillow-2-pack_91644-icon-2500x2500.jpg",
         box_id:2
      },
      {
         id:4,
         name:"Stuffed Animals",
         image:"https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0817201617082870M?resmode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1&wid=550&hei=550",
         box_id:2
      }
   ]
},
{
   id:3,
   name:"Cleaning Supplies",
   category:"Kitchen",
   move_id:1,
   move:{
      id:1,
      name:"Leaving for College",
      date:"2019-08-12",
      user_id:1
   },
   items:[
      {
         id:5,
         name:"Pillows",
         image:"https://www.greatsleep.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-tbp-master-catalog/default/dw9ff5c1cf/product-images/pillows/nautica/down-alt-pillow-2-pack-na-91644/nautica-down-alternative-pillow-2-pack_91644-icon-2500x2500.jpg",
         box_id:3
      },
      {
         id:6,
         name:"Stuffed Animals",
         image:"https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP0817201617082870M?resmode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1&wid=550&hei=550",
         box_id:3
      }
   ]
}];

const searchTerm = "Animals"

// function to filter sub-items
const filterItems = items => items.filter((i) => searchTerm ? i.name.includes(searchTerm) : i.name);

const filteredBoxes = data.map(boxes => {
  //filter sub-items
  const items = filterItems(boxes.items);
  //in case there is any item, return that boxes
  if (items.length) {  
    return Object.assign({}, boxes, { items })
  }
  // in case there is nothing, return false
  return false;
 }).filter(Boolean); // filter the boxes list removing the false values
 
console.log('filteredBoxes', filteredBoxes);
```